# Dynamically change a cell of table on radio button select in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

[image: Home Page]

I have developed the above sample page for booking ticket application in ASP.NET. I created the above layout using `<asp:Table>` tags. The `<asp:RadioButtonList>` is available in 1st cell of 2nd row and my main content should be in 2nd cell or 2nd row. Whenever i select a radio button the contents of 2nd cell in 2nd row should be updated automatically with new aspx page within this HomePage.aspx itself without reloading the page. I did this with `<frameset>` in HTML but i want to do this in ASP.NET web form as .aspx form. Is it possible to do this in `<asp:Table>` layout or i should use some other layout? Better in `<asp:Table>` layout if there is any solution.

The code i used for the above layout is as follows (only the HTML part of ASP.NET page)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TicketBookingRequest.HomePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Online Ticket Booking Request Portal</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Main.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/HomePage.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="main_form" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="main_table" CssClass="table" runat="server" GridLines="Both" Height="100%" Width="100%">
            <asp:TableRow ID="row_head" Height="100px">
                <asp:TableCell ID="logo_cell" Width="20%">

                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="65%">
                    <asp:Label ID="label_heading" Text="ONLINE TICKET BOOKING REQUEST PORTAL" CssClass="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="15%">
                    <div id="clockDisplay" class="clockStyle"></div>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="row_main" Height="500px">
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="menu_list" CssClass="list" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="menu_list_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="profile" Text="Edit User Profile"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="booking" Text="Request New Booking"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="status" Text="View Existing Booking Status"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="approval" Text="Request Awaiting Your Approval"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="cancel" Text="Cancel Existing Booking"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="master_cell" ColumnSpan="2" runat="server">
                    <div id="master_cell_div" runat="server"></div>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="row_foot" Height="10%">
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3">
                    <center>
                        <asp:Label Text="All Rights Reserved. Company Name @ 2016" CssClass="label" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label Text="Click here to contact us." CssClass="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </center>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The CS code using `<div>` tag and `InnerHtml` is as follows and this is working now after adding AutoPostBack="true"

```
protected void menu_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = menu_list.SelectedValue;
        if (value.Equals("profile"))
        {
            master_cell_div.InnerHtml = "<p>WELCOME TO PROFILE</p>";
        }
        else if (value.Equals("booking"))
        {
            master_cell_div.InnerHtml = "<p>WELCOME TO BOOKING</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            master_cell_div.InnerHtml = "<p>WELCOME TO OTHERS</p>";
        }
    }
```

The code i added for cell is,

```
<asp:TableCell ID="master_cell" ColumnSpan="2" Width="80%" runat="server">      
    <div id="master_cell_div" runat="server"></div>
</asp:TableCell>
```

But here instead of using InnerHtml is it possible to create 5 different .aspx forms and load them into the target cell on selecting these 5 different radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution using `JQuery`. In the main `HomePage.aspx` i added the following JQuery script,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function LoadProfile() {
        $("#master_cell_div").load("UserProfile.aspx #load_profile");
    }
    function LoadBooking() {
        $("#master_cell_div").load("BookTicket.aspx #load_booking");
    }
    function LoadStatus() {
        $("#master_cell_div").load("ViewStatus.aspx #load_status");
    }
    function LoadApproval() {
        $("#master_cell_div").load("ApproveRequest.aspx #load_approval");
    }
    function LoadCancel() {
        $("#master_cell_div").load("CancelTicket.aspx #load_cancel");
    }
</script>
```

Then i created 5 different .aspx pages with `<div>` tags as given below,

```
<div id="load_profile" runat="server">
    //Content goes here
</div>

<div id="load_booking" runat="server">
    //Content goes here
</div>

<div id="load_status" runat="server">
    //Content goes here
</div>

<div id="load_approval" runat="server">
    //Content goes here
</div>

<div id="load_cancel" runat="server">
    //Content goes here
</div>
```

Then i used the CS code in `HomePage.aspx.cs` back end code to load these JQuery scripts on radio button change as given below,

```
protected void menu_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = menu_list.SelectedValue;
    if (value.Equals("profile"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "LoadProfile();", true);
    }
    else if (value.Equals("booking"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "LoadBooking();", true);
    }
    else if (value.Equals("status"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "LoadStatus();", true);
    }
    else if (value.Equals("approval"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "LoadApproval();", true);
    }
    else if (value.Equals("cancel"))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "LoadCancel();", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly - you can use tables and modify a cell's content by assigning an ID= and a runat="server" to the td you want to make dynamic. In your codebehind, use the ID of the Td and the InnerHtml property.

```
 <asp:TableCell>
     <div id="myDynamicCell_1" runat="server"></div>
 </asp:TableCell>
```

then...

```
 myDynamicCell_1.InnerHtml = "<b>This is a test of the emergency dynamic system</b>";
```

Comment: But `<asp:TabelCell>` doesnt have the InnerHtml property in CS code..I tried. I think InnerHtml is a property only for HTML tag like `<td>`. In case of ASP.NET we use `<asp:TabelCell>` so its not supporting.

Comment: You're right - it's been a while. Then you simply place a div tag in the same way. I'll edit.  Sorry for mixup

Comment: Ok that should be better.

Comment: Hmm i tried this but its not working..no errors but when i click the radio buttons nothing happen. I added the CS script in my question.

Comment: Yes - you need to add the codebehind to your buttonclick event. I don't know where your button is, or I'd help with that. Wait - are you doing the addition client-side using JavaScript? My example is based on server-side/codebehind

Comment: I did, i have updated the code in question but still not working

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your button and your onclick event in codebehind?

Comment: I thought you were connection to a button.Click? The method you have is for a SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: yes its not a button click..its a RadioButtonList, i have mentioned that in my question itself since i posted it

Comment: try string value = menu_list.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: Did you set the autopostback=true for your radiobuttonlist?

Comment: oh i forgot that..its working now with AutoPostBack thank you...but here instead of using InnerHtml is it possible to create 5 different aspx pages and load them into the target cell on clicking radio buttons? because i want to create ASP.NET forms for these 5 pages also..

Comment: There are a few options open to you. #1 is to create the five different "pages" as DIVS in your master page with Visible=false; <div ID="div_Option_1" runat="server" Visible="false"></div> put your page elements in there. Then simply call myDynamicCell_1.InnerHtml = div_Option_1 and set visible=true; You'd have five different hidden divs, with one visible at once

Comment: #2 is to use frames